WordPress post table is inserting record but couldnt find source script or cron job
We are facing 2 issue on our WordPress site. Please help if you have been encountered same/similar issue before?

While checking tables, we have found that some records have been inserting as status auto draft into table post automatically as below. We couldn't find source.
enter image description here

Based on logs , sometimes post have been inserted / deleted as auto.
enter image description here


We would like to know , how post table have been inserted / deleted  automatically?
Please help on this issue. Thank you.

We have checked cron job from cpanel but there is no cron job.
We have tried to find any script that inserting post table. So far couldn't find anything related to this issue.

